# Poedit does not parse all strings in PHP files in "path"

Tags: php, poedit

Today i runt into this trouble when i tried to scan my plugin for translations and to create the localisation files for it, but i saw that Poedit scanned all files but did not parse all the strings.
For example if i had strings like this
`<?php _e('test string')?>` it's parsed, but if i had it in context like this

```
if($a == $b){
  _e('Everything is ok');
}else{
  _e('Error');
}
```

poedit did not parse any string.
Then i did a simple test and i put my messages in a line like this 
`<?php_e('test string'); _e('test string 2');?>` and poedit extracted them!

**Note:**
No error were thrown by poedit. All keywords are there, and searching by `(_,__,_e)`.

Comment: how does the quoted file look like? does it have <?php and ?> opening and closing tags and .php extension?

Comment: some of them are open just on the top, i thought this might be the issue so i tried to open at the begging of the file and to close it at the end of the file, but did not help. All class files are open only on top. all files use *.php extension.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have that Poedit doesn't seem to recognize strings after a comment somewhere in the file.

Today, it wouldn't see a lot of my strings. So I made a test.
This is a piece of code in the middle of the file:

```
//
// Check for valid address
//

echo __('Dit is een simpele test');
```

The string wasn't recognized, nor were any of the strings after that.
Removing the comment and a few other made Poedit see all the strings in the file.

To me, it seems it does it randomly, because a lot of files contain comments and it does recognize those strings. So it seems like a bug.

A colleague of mine noted that it only happens with single-line comments `//` and `#` and not using multi-line comments `/* */`. I tested it and it works, so that seems like a simple fix.

I'm using version 1.5.5 and I've had this problem with older versions.

(why can't I add comments?)

Comment: i use the same version. i had a lot of inline comments and i will give a try to your suggestion.

Comment: Poedit uses `xgettext` for extraction. There's most certainly not any Poedit bug related to comments and I am highly sceptical of there being any such xgettext bug either. Some rather old version versions of xgettext had problems with heredoc/nowdoc strings; I suspect that may be the actual cause here. Seeing that you're using the positively ancient 1.5.5 version of Poedit, it's a real possibility that your gettext-tools package is equally ancient.

Comment: Well that was in 2013, I don't know if you've noticed that. I don't even work there anymore, so I can't tell if they've updated or if the issue still exists. :)

Answer (score 1):

### I finally managed to fix it by just **re-indenting** heredoc code.

see, i used a code like this :

```
    $title = _x("Publish Later?","notif-panel","mytd");
    echo <<<a
    <tr><td ><label class="text-primary" for="notifaddedit-schedule-check">$title</label></td>
    <td>$datepicker</td></tr>

                    a;
```

then i changed it to:

```
    $title = _x("Publish Later?","notif-panel","mytd");
    echo <<<a
    <tr><td ><label class="text-primary" for="notifaddedit-schedule-check">$title</label></td>
    <td>$datepicker</td></tr>
a;
```

note the position of final **a;** that closes the heredoc, it souldn't have any tab or space before itself!

Answer (score 0):

Changing line endings on the file to Unix (from Mac OS 9) caused my missing strings to show up in Poedit.

Removing comments also worked but this is a better solution if it's universal. The comments issue seems to be a bug in Poedit.

Comment: It would be nice if you helped your fellow developers a bit and reported such bugs (with reproducible files) - I actually do care about bugs and do fix them ;) See my comment below for the supposed "comments bug" (not really), but I think it is indeed quite likely that `xgettext` cannot handle Classic Mac source files (it's a bit of a weird choice nowadays) - it's a Unix tool and has issues with Windows line endings too. On the other hand, if you mean the PO file was from Mac OS 9, that's something Poedit definitely should handle.